# wapiti crashes my ASP.NET project. Why? How do i fix it?

Tags: asp.net, security, crash, fuzzer, wapiti

Heres one scan of Wapiti. I notice when i had images uploaded (users can upload) i get a crash before `Launching module crlf`. So just using a fresh instance of my site i ran this and got the result below.

My questions are
1. How do i fix the crashes
2. How might i find out what is causing the crash. I used -v 2 to figure out the url and log them in my app. In both cases i dont see any issues and the project crashes outside of my code
3. How so i solve the unicode warning below?

```
 Wapiti-2.2.1 (wapiti.sourceforge.net)
..............................
 Notice
========
This scan has been saved in the file C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src/s
cans/localhost:17357.xml
You can use it to perform attacks without scanning again the web site with the "
-k" parameter
[*] Loading modules :
        mod_crlf, mod_exec, mod_file, mod_sql, mod_xss, mod_backup, mod_htaccess
, mod_blindsql, mod_permanentxss, mod_nikto

[+] Launching module crlf

[+] Launching module exec

[+] Launching module file

[+] Launching module sql
C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\attack\mod_sql.py:185: UnicodeWarning:
 Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpre
ting them as being unequal
  if (page, tmp) not in self.attackedPOST:

[+] Launching module xss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wapiti.py", line 449, in <module>
    wap.attack()
  File "wapiti.py", line 266, in attack
    x.attack(self.urls, self.forms)
  File "C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\attack\attack.py", line 121, i
n attack
    self.attackGET(page, dictio, headers)
  File "C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\attack\mod_xss.py", line 71, i
n attackGET
    self.findXSS(page, {}, "", code, "", payloads, headers["link_encoding"])
  File "C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\attack\mod_xss.py", line 306,
in findXSS
    dat = self.HTTP.send(url).getPage()
  File "C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\net\HTTP.py", line 94, in send

    info, data = self.h.request(target, headers = _headers)
  File "C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\net\httplib2\__init__.py", lin
e 1084, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, metho
d, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\net\httplib2\__init__.py", lin
e 888, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, he
aders)
  File "C:\unzipped\wapiti-2.2.1\wapiti-2.2.1\src\net\httplib2\__init__.py", lin
e 853, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 974, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 391, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 349, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "C:\dev\bin\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 397, in readline
    data = recv(1)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the re
mote host
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wapiti can crash applications because it uses a lot of your application.  Wapiti stack traced when doing an XSS test, and I don't think an xss test can crash an application.  However, by submitting a lot of 1 type of request,  then this could cause a DoS condition.   You need to track down the last request that Wapiti made.  Wapiti has a verbose mode, I think its -v and it will print out every request it makes.   Once you have the file that is crashing you should review it manually.

Wapiti's blind sql injection attack module uses mysql's benchmark() function which **WILL DoS** your mysql server,  I recommend turning this one off if you are have trouble scanning your entire site.

Comment: >>used -v 2 to figure out the url and log them in my app. In both cases i dont see any issues and the project crashes outside of my code

>Once you have the file that is crashing you should review it manually.

I tried by plugging in the url request i got and nothing happened. Sometimes the Wapiti writes a url that isnt in my log `protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) { filewr.WriteLine(Context.Request.RawUrl);` It crashes inn WebDev dll. Which isnt me or libs i use (elmah, sqlite). Also i notice a crash when it visits one of my image urls (/blah.[png|jpg])

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know asp.net very well.  I do like using wapiti.   maybe you can attach a debugger or profiler to see where your app is crashing.